# Iframe Onload New Link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

I have here an iframe which mirrors the appscript that I have made. How can i redirect the user to another page when the link was changed or when they submit the form?

```
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
      <iframe id="main_iframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx4G-n0ZTowZENy4haaUyI3s-S5WLbAD2yUVRRpNZDBP06jKlTox_eqFEBZXxOodSeq/exec" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
var load = 0;

document.getElementById('main_iframe').onload = function(){
    /*Execute on every reload on iFrame*/
    load++;
    if(load > 1){
        /*Second reload is a submit*/
        window.open("https://digitsorani.net/mulawin-pasahero-success/","_top")
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I assume you mean that within your apps script you have a form and you want to be able to redirect to another page when they submit the form within the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope that It might work for you.

```
       <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
          <iframe id="main_iframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx4G-n0ZTowZENy4haaUyI3s-S5WLbAD2yUVRRpNZDBP06jKlTox_eqFEBZXxOodSeq/exec" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
  
        <script type="text/javascript">      
        document.querySelector("iframe").addEventListener( "load", function(e) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            //alert(this.nodeName);
            //console.log(e.target);
            window.open("https://digitsorani.net/mulawin-pasahero-success/","_top");
        
        } );    
       </script>
```